# Search tweets for specific URL Twitter API 1.1

Tags: api, twitter, tweepy

I am looking for all those tweets which contain the "specific url". But upon query, empty set is returned from twitter API 1.1 search.

Example:
To search tweets which contain following URL:

http://wattsupwiththat.com/2013/07/29/al-gores-reality-minions-think-the-north-pole-is-melting-except-thats-not-a-photo-of-the-north-pole/

1. Twitter API 1.1 Search: returns no result. [online api console](https://dev.twitter.com/console)
2. Twitter search returns lot of tweets: [link](https://twitter.com/search?q=wattsupwiththat.com/2013/07/29/al-gores-reality-minions-think-the-north-pole-is-melting-except-thats-not-a-photo-of-the-north-pole/&src=typd&f=realtime)

Why is twitter api 1.1. behaving differently ?
Is there any other alternative to search URL from tweets, if not Twitter API 1.1 ?

Comment: How are you sending the query? Are you URL encoding the text?

Comment: yes I am encoding the url text. 
I am using tweepy python library but I have tried from curl as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like no one has tweeted that - see https://snap.apigee.com/1iIPIMh and https://twitter.com/search?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwattsupwiththat.com%2F2013%2F07%2F29%2Fal-gores-reality-minions-think-the-north-pole-is-melting-except-thats-not-a-photo-of-the-north-pole%2F&src=typd&f=realtime

If you search for a URL which has been frequently tweeted - you'll see lots of results such as https://snap.apigee.com/1oZPWpO

Comment: In the question, I have cited the link of twitter search result and it  has quite a number of tweets which has the link.